# How to restrict user to Upload only 3 images?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, gdlib

I'm creating a web app in Codeigniter. Here's the code in VIEW's.

```
<div class="bold light-gray">Add a photo or two!</div>
<p class="short">Or three, or more! Prospective Buyers love photos that highlight the features of your parts or gear.</p>
<form class="ajaxform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='<?php echo site_url('UploadImage/upload_Image');?>'>
<input type="hidden" name="do" value="upload"/>
Upload your image <input type="file" name="Filedata" id="photo" onChange="abc()" />
<input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="<?php echo $timestamp;?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo md5('unique_salt' . $timestamp);?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $customer['id'];?>" />
</form>
</div>
<!-- /.box.center -->
<?php echo form_open('/secure/add_item/'.$id, array('id'=>'listitem') ); ?>
<div id="img_cant"> <?php  
if(isset($images) && !empty($images)) {
foreach($images as $key=>$img){
 ?>
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $img; ?>" name="images[]" id="hid_<?php echo $key; ?>">
 <?php 
}
} 
?>
</div>
```

I want to allow the user to just add 3 or 4 images maximum. How to do that?

Comment: Use count function to count array length

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $count=count($_FILES['name']);
if($count>3)
{
echo "Your error message";
}
else{
echo "your desired activity";
}?>
```

Comment: i want something like http://www.geartrade.com/sell [link](http://www.geartrade.com/sell)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can call this function while submit your form

```
var file_nu = $("input:file")[0].files.length;
if(file_nu >3)//apply your condition here
{
 return FALSE;
}else{
 return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: i want something like http://www.geartrade.com/sell [link](http://www.geartrade.com/sell)